# when the amalgamated product is trivial.

Tags: group-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g: A\rightarrow C$ are two surjective homomorphisms of (non trivial) groups.
such that $A$ is an infinite group and $B, C$ are finite but not trivial groups.
Under which sufficient and necessary condition the amalgamated product $B\ast_{A}C$ is a trivial group ?

Comment: What makes you think such a condition exists?

Comment: One sufficient condition is $g$ maps $\ker f$ onto $C$ and $f$ maps $\ker g$ onto $B$.

Comment: The condition that $A$ is infinite is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If $K_f$ and $K_g$ are their kernels, the amalgam is trivial iff $K_fK_g=A$.

Indeed, for $G$ the amalgam and $H$ another group, a homomorphism $G\to H$ is the same as two homomorphisms $u:B\to H$, $v:C\to H$ such that $uf=vg$. In turn, this is the same as two homomorphism $U,V:A\to H$ such that $U$ is trivial on $K_f$, $V$ is trivial on $K_g$, and $U=V$. In other words, it's the same as a homomorphism $A/K_fK_g\to H$. So the amalgam is just $A/K_fK_g$.

(The condition $K_fK_g=A$ is equivalent to the projection of $K_f$ on $A/K_g$ being surjective, and is also equivalent to the projection of $K_g$ on $A/K_f$ being surjective. These conditions were evoked by Derek Holt in a comment. Also, assuming (in)finite of some of the given groups is unnecessary.)